# Double IP weekend + IP per win + IP per day

Tags: league-of-legends

Sometimes, there are double IP weekends in League of Legends.

How do IP boosts,per Win or over days, affect the won IP during that time?

**Possible Scenarios (assuming a win without the weekend and boots gives X IP):**

- X * 4 : All bonuses stack additively (normal + double weekend + per win boost + der day boost = 4) and are multiplied afterwards
- X * 6 : normal + double weekend counts as normal and per win boost + per day boost are multiplied afterwards = X * 2 * 3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IP boosts work **additively**. Buying different boosts will stack (this does not work when buying the same boost).

For every boost, you earn the IP of the base IP you earned, whether it's a won match or a lost one. Of course the First Win of the Day boost (which cannot be enhanced and is fixed on 150 IP) will only get taken into account when you actually win a match, which is available after every 22 hours when consumed.

**Formula:** Base IP + any boost

**Example:** Base IP + IP boost + Weekend Bonus + First Win of the Day gives 80 + 80 + 80 + 150 IP = 390 IP from a single match.

**As a side note:**

- The maximum amount of the base IP from a winning match is 168. To earn 168 IP the game must be ranked and has to last 55 minutes or longer. The maximum amount of IP from a match in total is: 168 + 168 + 168 + 150 = 654 IP (Base IP + IP boost timed + IP boost per win + First Win of the Day). When there is a Double IP Weekend going on you can add an additional 168 IP which gives you a whopping 822 IP for a won match.
- The maximum amount of the base IP from a lost match is 95. That means you can earn up to 190 IP (Base IP + IP boost timed). And of course during Double IP weekends makes that 285 IP.

(Source: http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Influence_Points#Trivia)

Comment: this is not answering my question. i ask how it works with the buyable boosts.

Comment: I'm sorry I misread that. IP boosts work additively, not multiplicatively. That means it basically works like the Weekend Bonus.  Example: Base IP + IP boost + Weekend Bonus (IE: 80 + 80 + 80)

Comment: Different IP boosts do stack indeed. You can get like 600 IP just off one game (including First Win of the Day). This is based off my own experience, there is no concrete source for this. Do mind that buying the same boost more than once does not stack.

Comment: Like I said, if you gain 80 IP from a match, you get another 80 from the boost and another 80 from the Weekend Bonus.

Comment: oh no! sorry its my fault! i read it wrong

Comment: Haha, I was already thinking how that could be wrong.